# ASP.Net which tool for black background + show page in front?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I search a control, tool or way to implement a well known feature - i dont know this name so i cant google it:

I want to click on a button and then the actual site stays the same, but a tranparent layer appears and a second webpage (often use for pictures) come to the front until i click it away.

Whats that called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with ModalPopup from the AjaxControlToolkit: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

If you want to go the jQuery route, there is a jQuery popup:
http://plugins.jquery.com/popup/